# Change img source when key is pressed and back when released

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**What I want to accomplish:**  When the user presses the SPACEBAR the image source should change from `spacebar.png` to `spacebar_pressed.png`. When the user releases the key the image should change back to the default.

I have looked around everywhere and tried several possibilities but none worked. Bear in mind that I'm not very good with Javascript.

**HTML:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/spacebar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Spacebar Simulator 2017</h1>
    <img src="assets/spacebar.png" id="spacebar">
</body>
</html>
```

This is my most recent code I have tried:

```
$("#spacebar").on("keydown", function(e){
    var code = e.keyCode;
    if(code == 32){
     document.getElementById("spacebar").src="../assets/spacebar_pressed.png";
    }
});
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the `javascript` from your question... What have you tried so far? This isn't a free writing service so to give you a solution in javascript you must have some javascript for people to work with....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `keypress` and `attr` function to accomplish such task.

In the callback, you have your event object, its attribute `which` is the keyCode, it represents the key that was pressed. The keyCode is 32 for spacebar.

When a key gets released on the DOM, the url changes again explicitly.

```js
$(function() {
  var myRealUrl = "http://hammerjs.github.io/assets/img/stackoverflow-icon.svg";
  $("body").on("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.which == 32) {
      $("#spacebar").attr("src", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png");
      console.log('pressed');
    }
  });

  $("body").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 32) {
      $("#spacebar").attr("src", myRealUrl);
      console.log('released');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/*Demo Use*/
img {
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://hammerjs.github.io/assets/img/stackoverflow-icon.svg" id="spacebar" />
```

Comment: I appreciate you putting in the effort trying to help me out. I still can't get this to work. Is there anything I did wrong when copying your code?

`var myRealUrl = "../assets/spacebar.png";
$("body").on("keydown", function (e) {
  if(e.which == 32){   
    $("#spacebar").attr("src", "../assets/spacebar_pressed.png")
  }
});

$("body").keyup(function (e) {
    $("#spacebar").attr("src", myRealUrl)
});`

Comment: @David Check your browser console for errors. If you have this script running within the `head` tag and haven't placed it within `jQuery`'s DOM ready function then you will no doubt find an error in the console. **Also** be sure to add the `jQuery` library before you attempt to use it, order matters.

Comment: do you need  `../` or no? in your html file `../` does not exist. @David

Comment: thanks for the help and for reminding me with the missing part@NewToJS

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, the jQuery is linked in the HTML before my other js file. I tried removing the link to my custom js and moving the code inside <script> tags in the HTML, which solved it. It is now working, but I do not understand why it was not when the code was in a separate file.

Comment: Oh and by the way, I do need the punctuation before the path to the image, as they are not placed in the same folder as my js files.

Comment: @David Well in the source code you provided `spacebar.js` is linked before the `jQuery` library so if that contained and `jQuery` it would cause a syntax error. We can only go by what you provide hence my suggestion to check the order of those `script` tags and DOM ready function.

Comment: I understand, my bad. I updated the original to match the head I'm using now.

Comment: Update: I moved the line where I link to my custom js file down right before the closing body tag. This way the code works in its own js file, and not only in <script> tags in the HTML. Thank you, and @turmuka for clarifying everything to me.

Comment: @David Place your source code within the `jQuery` DOM ready function as shown in the answer above will allow you to keep your `script` in the `head` tag. `jQuery` DOM ready function   `$(function(){/*Source code here*/});`